# problem proof of induction $2\cdot3^0+2\cdot3^1+2\cdot3^2+...+2\cdot3^{n-1}=3^n-1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, induction, education

I need to prove that $2\cdot3^0+2\cdot3^1+2\cdot3^2+...+2\cdot3^{n-1}=3^n-1,\, n=1,2,3,4...$

I know when n = 1 the left side $=2\cdot3^{1-1}=2$. The right side is $2^n - 1=2^1 - 1 = 1$. Thus the statement is true for $n = 1$.

True for $n = k$, that is $2\cdot3^0+2\cdot3^1+2\cdot3^2+...+2\cdot3^{k-1}=3^k-1$

I have problem to prove that the statement is true for $n = k + 1$. I don't know how I should continue...

Comment: Rigorous proofs are in the answers. Notice, however, that if you subtract $1$ from the base-3 number $10....00$ (with $n$ zeroes), you get $2...22$ ($n$ digits), which is basically what your sum says.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So we assume that
$$2\cdot3^0+2\cdot3^1+2\cdot3^2+...+2\cdot3^{k-1}=3^k-1$$
Now add $2 \cdot 3^{k}$ to both sides:
$$ 2\cdot3^0+2\cdot3^1+2\cdot3^2+...+2\cdot3^{k-1}+2\cdot 3^{k}=2\cdot 3^k +3^k-1 = 3 \cdot 3^{k}-1 = 3^{k+1}-1, $$
which is of the same form as the $n=k$ case with $k$ replaced by $k+1$, and hence the statement is true for $n=k+1$.

Comment: Ah, bollocks! Just beat me to it. :)

Comment: Upvote for speed by the way.

Comment: @chappers Thank you very much. I forgot often to put it on the right side as well, so therefore I could not solve it. But fortunately that you showed me how it works.

Comment: Haha @Aleksandar

Answer (score 2):

$2 \times3^0+2 \times 3^1+...+2 \times 3^{n-1}+2 \times 3^n=3^n-1+2 \times 3^n=3^{n+1}-1$

Hope this helps.

Comment: Upvote for you to :) anyway, thank you too for your answer :)